# How to change the window type?

Tags: interface

I was doing some stuff and this window popped up
[image: blender UI]

I don't know how to get rid of it and I want this window back:
[image: properties panel]

Comment: you might want to read the following links (it will save you hours and headaches down the line): http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_types http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames andhttp://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system

Answer (score 6):

You can change the editor type in the dropdown icon in the header:

[image]

The one you want is the *Properties* editor.