# My "Info Header" was replaced when I went into Node Editing Mode. How do I get the default bar back?

Tags: interface

I am working on an animation, and I had to change it to node editing mode for a while, but the file bar at the top of the screen is replaced with the bar at the bottom of the screen that says View, Select, Add, etc. How do i get my "info header" back so i can change my mode to compositing mode? Or does anyone know a shortcut to get to compositing mode? Thanks

Please help ASAP this is a timed animation project I am working on

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24386/how-to-change-the-window-type ?

Comment: for a list of shrtcuts to different window types see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/17937/1853

Answer (score -1):

Info   is a window like any other and can be selected in any window via the drop down/pop up on the left top or bottom of the window. Blue circular icon Info.
Or hover mouse over that list and press keyboard letter i

Is that what you meant?