# Object Editing View

Tags: light, lighting

Want to edit the Area lamp and make stadium lights but can't go to the edit view (usually on the right).

[image]

Comment: Looks like this one https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned but for Mac

Comment: Read: [How can I reset my menus](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus/8394#8394) and [how to change the window type](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24386/how-to-change-the-window-type)